# Find the minimum of a multivariate polynomial function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Suppose,  $$p(x,y,z)=18x^2y+3y^2z+4z^2x-18xyz$$

Then prove that, $$\min_{x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}} p(x,y,z) =0$$

Clearly when $xyz=0$, $p$ is non-negative for $x,y,z\geq0$.

We need to handle the case when $xyz=0$. I have tried to find stationary points of $p$. However, this is very complicated as the gradient is system of second-order polynomials.

Also, I tried to show directly that $p\geq0$ for all non-negative $x,y,z$. It is clear that when $x\geq z$, $p$ is non-negative. But, when $z>x$, I am unable to draw any conclusion.

Comment: Please show the own effort to solve the issue. As it stays, the question does not satisfy the conditions for a "good" question on this site. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question - The question is - as it stays - in danger to be closed (after some very few votes).

Comment: I added whatever I tried. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x,y,z\in\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, your polynomial $p(x,y,z)$
looks to me like it was specially constructed so that the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#) could be applied:

$$\begin{aligned}p(x,y,z)+18xyz&=18x^2y+3y^2z+4z^2x\\
&\ge 3\sqrt [3]{18\cdot 3\cdot 4x^3y^3z^3}\\
&=18xyz\end{aligned}
$$

This implies,

$$p(x,y,z)\ge 0$$

Finally, note that the equality $p(x,y,z)=0$ can hold, so you prove that

$$\min_{x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}} p(x,y,z) =0.$$